# Find out which is most popular keyword from google?

Tags: seo, keyword, friendly-url, slug

How do I find out which is most popular keywords in google?

Possible Keywords,

1 - London Business

2 - Online Business London

Then I need to make a decision for URL friendly (SEO), example:

/london-business

/online-business-london

/online-business/london

Comment: This is better off on [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Google Adwords Keyword tool: https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal

this will give you the related keywords, the Global Monthly searches, relevance, etc. Then compare the metrics for each keyword.

Now '/online-business-london' is probably more SEO friendly than the other options. And a more specific set of keywords is preferred than a general one because you will be targeting people that are interested in 'online business' rather than 'business' in general.

Comment: I have entered two keywords... one of them say ay 'Competition' is high and the Global Monthly Searches is lower? and other one say Competition is low and Global Monthly Searches is high.. would would be better option?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.google.com/trends?q=London+Business%2C+Online+Business+London&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0

But anyways the best option should be /london-business/online